# How to Remove Toolbar from QToolBox control in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

How to Remove Toolbar from `QToolBox` in Qt?

Normal Toolbox looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove this button written with Page 1. Something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this makes much sense, since those buttons are needed for the functionality of the QToolBox. If you want a stack of widgets for which you can manually control if they are shown or not, then [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstackedwidget.html) provides similar functionality without displaying any elements of its own.

**edit:** No, as the QToolBox it doesn't come with a scrollbar. But since you 'fill' it with widgets of your own, which then are displayed with setCurrentWidget, you can use for example [QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qscrollarea.html) and placing your own widgets inside it.

Comment: i want a vertical scrollbar also in QStackedWidget does it have that ?